# Powering a 2amp micro-usb device over cat5

Tags: usb, ethernet, cables, usb-device, poe

There was once a phone in my bathroom, so now there is an LV box with a Cat5 cable in it at the end of a 30ft run.

Can I hack something together to power a Google Home Mini with that cable?

Comment: Is it just a point-to-point cable? No router or devices in between? You could use a POE injector and tap off the power on the other end.

Comment: Yes, just a point-to-point cable. I understand that PoE if 48VAC, and, depending on the kind, up to 0.9mA. How do I convert it to 5V DC and 1.8A?

Comment: are you sure that it is a category 5 cable?

Comment: There exists plenty of off the shelf devices to do exactly what you intend and step down the 48 V _DC_ to 5 V.

Comment: What would it be called: an adapter, a converter or an inverter?

Answer (score 2):

Use a real/ active poe injector. At 30 ft, or 60ft round trip at 22 awg or smaller, and 2 Amps, you cannot use a passive injector or usb to Ethernet adapter without significant voltage drop at the other end. An active injector will give true Poe power, and a Poe to 5V 2 Amp switching adapter at the device end would give you what the device needs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any expensive and fancy PoE injectors or like. And 48V is overkill. All you need is an ordinary 12-V power supply (AC-DC adapter), and a DC-DC converter to 5V. Any [kind from eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Mini-3A-DC-DC-Converter-Adjustable-Step-down-Power-Supply-Module-replace/322851116528) will do the job.

The current over your cable will be under 1 A, which should be absolutely fine if you quadruple current ampacity of CAT5 wires by using two twister pairs for +12 V and return ground.

Comment: How would I convert it to the micro-usb format?

Comment: @Wynne, As I understand, the Google speaker needs only DC power over u-USB connector. You feed your CAT cable with 12V, connect the other end of cable to the DC-DC converter input, observing power polarity. Then get a regular USB cable with micro-B connector, strip it short, and solder black wire to ground (-) terminal of the output of the DC-DC converter, and red wire to (+) terminal.